# Replace nulls with the previous non-null value

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I am using Amazon Athena engine version 1, which is based on Presto 0.172.

Consider the example data set:

| id | date_column | col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/03/2021 | NULL |
| 1 | 02/03/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 15/03/2021 | 2 |
| 1 | 16/03/2021 | NULL |
| 1 | 17/03/2021 | NULL |
| 1 | 30/03/2021 | NULL |
| 1 | 30/03/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 31/03/2021 | NULL |

I would like to replace all NULLs in the table with the last non-NULL value i.e. I want to get:

| id | date_column | col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/03/2021 | NULL |
| 1 | 02/03/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 15/03/2021 | 2 |
| 1 | 16/03/2021 | 2 |
| 1 | 17/03/2021 | 2 |
| 1 | 30/03/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 30/03/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 31/03/2021 | 1 |

I was thinking of using a `lag` function with `IGNORE NULLS` option but unfortunately, `IGNORE NULLS` is not supported by Athena engine version 1 (it is also not supported by Athena engine version 2, which is based on Presto 0.217).

How to achieve the desired format without using the `IGNORE NULLS` option?

Here is some template for generating the example table:

```sql
WITH source1 AS (
SELECT
 *
FROM (
  VALUES
  (1, date('2021-03-01'), NULL),
  (1, date('2021-03-02'), 1),
  (1, date('2021-03-15'), 2),
  (1, date('2021-03-16'), NULL),
  (1, date('2021-03-17'), NULL),
  (1, date('2021-03-30'), NULL), 
  (1, date('2021-03-30'), 1), 
  (1, date('2021-03-31'), NULL)
) AS t (id, date_col, col1)
)

SELECT
  id
, date_col
, col1
-- This doesn't work as IGNORE NULLS is not supported.
-- CASE 
--   WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN col1
--   ELSE lag(col1) OVER IGNORE NULLS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_col) 
-- END AS col1_lag_nulls_ignored
FROM
  source1
ORDER BY
  date_co
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing similar questions on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886073/last-observation-carried-forward-ignore-nulls-in-lag) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19012333/10957519)), the below solution will work for all column types (including Strings and dates):

```sql
WITH source1 AS (
SELECT
 *
FROM (
  VALUES
  (1, date('2021-03-01'), NULL),
  (1, date('2021-03-02'), 1),
  (1, date('2021-03-15'), 2),
  (1, date('2021-03-16'), NULL),
  (1, date('2021-03-17'), NULL),
  (1, date('2021-03-30'), 1), 
  (1, date('2021-03-31'), NULL)
) AS t (id, date_col, col1)
)

, grouped AS (
SELECT
  id
, date_col
, col1
-- If the row has a value in a column, then this row and all subsequent rows 
-- with a NULL (before the next non-NULL value) will be in the same group.
, sum(CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_col) AS grp
FROM 
 source1
)

SELECT
  id
, date_col
, col1
-- max is used instead of first_value, since in cases where there will
-- be multiple records with NULL on the same date, the first_value may 
-- still return a NULL.
, max(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY id, grp ORDER BY date_col) AS col1_filled
, grp
FROM
  grouped 
ORDER BY
  date_col
```